# size_t template parameter in std::array

Tags: c++, stdarray, size-t

The std::array template parameters are `template < class T, size_t N > class array;` where N stands for the number of elements in the array.

My doubt is why is the type `std::size_t`? Isn't std::size_t an alias for the size of an object/pointer in bytes. [std::size_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/size_t/%3E)

Why is it used to denote the number of elements in `std::array` here?

Comment: It is also the default size and index type for pretty much every container and algorithm in the standard library. The notable exception being to represent the distance between elements, where the value can be negative.

Comment: Note that the term "object" is kind of overloaded in C++. Sure you have the OOP terminology floating around, but in [C++ just about everything is an object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object). It is literally easier to list what isn't an object than what is.

Comment: Sorry I'm a new user, thank you for pointing that out David, I've made the changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type `std::size_t` is defined to be a numeric type that can represent the size of the largest possible object (say, *N* bytes).

The largest object could be an array, and the array with the most possible objects is therefore an array of *N* `char`s.

So, [`std::size_t` makes sense for array indexes and dimensions too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59728149/4386278).

You should stick to this convention as much as possible, because otherwise you potentially introduce bugs:

> `std::size_t` is commonly used for array indexing and loop counting. Programs that use other types, such as `unsigned int`, for array indexing may fail on, e.g. 64-bit systems when the index exceeds `UINT_MAX` or if it relies on 32-bit modular arithmetic ([cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t))

We could have had a `std::index_t` instead, but it would have been the same as `std::size_t`, so that's pointless.